# Trouble pip installing psutil on Mojave

Tags: python, macos, pip, macos-mojave, psutil

I'm trying to install psutil with the Homebrew version of Python on OSX Mojave.

Running:

```
pip3 install psutil 2> error.log
```

The console output is:

```
Collecting psutil
  Using cached psutil-5.7.2.tar.gz (460 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: psutil
  Building wheel for psutil (setup.py) ... error
  Running setup.py clean for psutil
Failed to build psutil
Installing collected packages: psutil
    Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
```

and the error messages:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ps/v2x3jwmd0nn5ylp886xdzb1w0000gn/T/pip-install-6w_gsm04/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ps/v2x3jwmd0nn5ylp886xdzb1w0000gn/T/pip-install-6w_gsm04/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/ps/v2x3jwmd0nn5ylp886xdzb1w0000gn/T/pip-wheel-pcxfxegq
       cwd: /private/var/folders/ps/v2x3jwmd0nn5ylp886xdzb1w0000gn/T/pip-install-6w_gsm04/psutil/
  Complete output (49 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_contracts.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_memleaks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  copying psutil/tests/test_testutils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
  running build_ext
  building 'psutil._psutil_osx' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/arch
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/arch/osx
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=572 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_common.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=572 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c psutil/_psutil_posix.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_posix.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=572 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c psutil/_psutil_osx.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_osx.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=572 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c psutil/arch/osx/process_info.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/arch/osx/process_info.o
  clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_common.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_posix.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_osx.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/arch/osx/process_info.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-38-darwin.so -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit
  ld: unknown option: -platform_version
  clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ps/v2x3jwmd0nn5ylp886xdzb1w0000gn/T/pip-install-6w_gsm04/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ps/v2x3jwmd0nn5ylp886xdzb1w0000gn/T/pip-install-6w_gsm04/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/ps/v2x3jwmd0nn5ylp886xdzb1w0000gn/T/pip-record-3swdof00/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/psutil
         cwd: /private/var/folders/ps/v2x3jwmd0nn5ylp886xdzb1w0000gn/T/pip-install-6w_gsm04/psutil/
    Complete output (49 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_contracts.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_memleaks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_testutils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_osx' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/arch
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/arch/osx
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=572 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_common.o
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=572 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c psutil/_psutil_posix.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_posix.o
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=572 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c psutil/_psutil_osx.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_osx.o
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=572 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c psutil/arch/osx/process_info.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/arch/osx/process_info.o
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_common.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_posix.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_osx.o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/arch/osx/process_info.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-38-darwin.so -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit
    ld: unknown option: -platform_version
    clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/ps/v2x3jwmd0nn5ylp886xdzb1w0000gn/T/pip-install-6w_gsm04/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/ps/v2x3jwmd0nn5ylp886xdzb1w0000gn/T/pip-install-6w_gsm04/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/ps/v2x3jwmd0nn5ylp886xdzb1w0000gn/T/pip-record-3swdof00/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/psutil Check the logs for full command output.
```

I don't understand what the source of the error is. The linker seems to have a problem with the flag `-platform_version` even though it's not in any of the previous lines.

I have searched for other solutions that usually involve some variant of

```
xcode-select --install
xcode-select --reset
```

I've tried all that, including reinstalling command line tools but nothing seems to fix it. Is the issue potentially that I have to upgrade to Catalina? I've been putting that off because of its lack of 32-bit support. Thanks.

edit: This is what I get with "ld -v"

```
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-450.3
BUILD 18:16:53 Apr  5 2019
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: LLVM version 10.0.1, (clang-1001.0.46.4) (static support for 22, runtime is 22)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 10.0.1 (tapi-1001.0.4.1)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to post the output of `ld -v` ?

Comment: Hi, I edited to include that output

Comment: It seems related to Xcode and Command Line Tools not updated to the latest version, which includes `ld` that *does* support `-platform-version`. Did you install the latest Xcode for Mojave? (11.3)

Comment: Thanks so much, finally got it done! Turns out I didn't have Xcode at all (don't know when it was uninstalled). Couldn't download it without Catalina so bit the bullet and upgraded. Then installed Xcode and reinstalled command line tools and it works.