# `pip install psutil` is throwing `error: Unsupported architecture`. Any workarounds?

Tags: python, xcode, pip

I want to install psutil on my `macOS Catalina`, for which I am doing `pip install psutil`, but it doesn't succeed. Instead I get multiple error messages being thrown from `Xcode` saying that the architecture is not supported. Has anyone faced similar issues? Here's the entire output:

```
Collecting psutil
  Using cached psutil-5.7.2.tar.gz (460 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for psutil, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: psutil
    Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/sanjibanbairagya/code/.envs/airbase_backend/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/53/072hdjvd63z1p57y512596rc0000gn/T/pip-install-a_22z6dq/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/53/072hdjvd63z1p57y512596rc0000gn/T/pip-install-a_22z6dq/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/53/072hdjvd63z1p57y512596rc0000gn/T/pip-record-ca9qt6ec/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sanjibanbairagya/code/.envs/airbase_backend/include/site/python3.8/psutil
         cwd: /private/var/folders/53/072hdjvd63z1p57y512596rc0000gn/T/pip-install-a_22z6dq/psutil/
    Complete output (141 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_contracts.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_memleaks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    copying psutil/tests/test_testutils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_osx' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/arch
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/arch/osx
    xcrun -sdk macosx clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=572 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Users/sanjibanbairagya/code/.envs/airbase_backend/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_common.o
    In file included from psutil/_psutil_common.c:9:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
    #error Unsupported architecture
     ^
    In file included from psutil/_psutil_common.c:9:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from psutil/_psutil_common.c:9:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from psutil/_psutil_common.c:9:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
    typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
    typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from psutil/_psutil_common.c:9:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from psutil/_psutil_common.c:9:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/sanjibanbairagya/code/.envs/airbase_backend/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/53/072hdjvd63z1p57y512596rc0000gn/T/pip-install-a_22z6dq/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/53/072hdjvd63z1p57y512596rc0000gn/T/pip-install-a_22z6dq/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/53/072hdjvd63z1p57y512596rc0000gn/T/pip-record-ca9qt6ec/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sanjibanbairagya/code/.envs/airbase_backend/include/site/python3.8/psutil Check the logs for full command output.
```

Also, here's the output of `uname -a` in case that's useful: `Darwin Sanjibans-MacBook-Pro.local 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Aug 31 22:12:52 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Is there a fix / workaround for the above issue? Any kind of help whatsoever would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of the error, I was using `Python 3.8.2`.

This was fixed after upgrading to `Python 3.8.5`

Comment: The OS-provided version (/usr/bin/python3) in Catalina is 3.8.2. I installed the latest python 3.8 using MacPorts, pointed the virtual environment to it, and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 20):

I came across [this](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1832#issuecomment-704596756) answer that worked like a magic for me.

While I was hitting this when installing a different package (numphy, nltk, etc.) I was able to work around this by exporting an environment variable

```sh
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - also it is similar to [Trouble pip installing psutil on Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987934/trouble-pip-installing-psutil-on-mojave).

Couple of fixes that worked for me:

- this only happens on python 3.8, python 3.7 seems to work
- updating to the latest, Command Line Tools for XCode 12 worked (either try `xcode-select --install` or download it directly from [More downloads for Apple developers](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) (requires login))

Comment: I'm getting this with Command Line Tools for 12.0.1 (12A7300) and the 12.2 beta (12B5018i). Any other ideas? I'm able to install some packages but not others it seems. As far as I can tell `which pip` and `which python` are both way outside of Xcode land but something is going back there